# how to get the value from $(this)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project I have this Editor Template.
I cannot debug it in the IE Developer Tools as it is in a popup window. I do not have access to the other browsers.
So my jquery is not picking up the values for the url, employeeId and the businessUnitId.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.Models.BusinessUnitSelected>" %>

<tr>
    <td><%: Model.BusinessUnit.BusinessUnitName %></td>
    <td>

    <%: Html.CheckBoxFor( 
            x => x.Selected,
            new RouteValueDictionary 
            { 
                { "data-url", Url.Action("AddBusinessUnitForEmployee", "DataService") }, 
                { "data-employeeId", Model.EmployeeId }, 
                { "data-businessUnitId", Model.BusinessUnit.BusinessUnitId } 
            } 

       ) %> 

    </td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
            var elementId = $(this).attr('id');
            alert("elementId = " + elementId);
            var url = $(this).val('data-url');
            alert("url = " + url);
            var employeeId = $(this).val('data-employeeId');
            alert("employeeId = " + employeeId);
            var businessUnitId = $(this).val('data-businessUnitId');
            alert("businessunitId = " + businessUnitId);
            var selectedFlag = $(this).is(':checked');
            alert("selectedFlag = " + selectedFlag);

            dataService.saveSelection(
            employeeId,
            businessUnitId,
            selectedFlag,
            elementId,
            SavedSetting,
            url
        );
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` is used to get/set the `value` attribute, <s>you should use .`attr()` instead:</s>

<s>eg. `$(this).attr('data-url');`</s>

**edit**

@Dima Suggests the correct way to access HTML5 `data-*` attributes - by using `.data()`, eg. `$(this).data('url');`

**note:** You should hyphenate words in your `data-` attributes otherwise you'll have trouble reading their values when using `.data()`. See below:-

```
<input type="text" data-employeeId="1" />

console.log($('input[type="text"]').data('employeeId')); // (undefined!)
```

This is because `$('input[type="text"]').data('employeeId')` is trying to read `data-employee-id`, using the latter you can then access the data using `.data('employeeId')` or `.data('employee-id')`.

> All data-* names are stored in camelCase in the jQuery data object,
> using W3C rules.
>
> So, data-caMEL-case becomes the camelCase property in the data object
> and should be accessed using .data("camelCase"). Because many people
> will use .data("camel-case") instead, we convert that to camelCase as
> well, but only if no data item named camel-case is found so it's
> faster to use the first form. If you get the entire data object using
> code like data = jQuery.data(elem), you must use data.camelCase to
> access the data item.

Comment: You won the race. I will tick you when the time limit allows me to. Thank you.

Comment: Dima's answer is the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `$(this).data('url')`, `$(this).data('employeeId')` and so on.

Comment: ahh.. forgot about `.data()`, +1

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$(this).attr('data-employeeId');
```

Comment: Also ... data() method as of jQuery 1.4.3  : http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: "To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method"

Answer (score 0):

Cache the $(this) on the beginning of the function .click so your javascript will work faster. Try $this = $(this) and then use $this instead of $(this).

```
$('tr input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      url = $(this).val('data-url'); // Wrong
      url = $this.attr('data-url'); // Or
      url = $this.data('url');
  ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the $(this).attr(key) instead of $(this).val(key).**

```
$(this).attr("data-url");
```

instead of

```
$(this).val('data-url');
```